# Brown spots and holes on calathea leaves

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care

I bought a calathea roseopicta plant a few weeks back. At the time only a few leaves had those brown holes and I didn't really think that would be a big issue. I watered and cared for the plant properly, but this thing started happening to the other leaves as well and recently I started noticing the same thing happening to one of my other calathea plant leaf.I'm
not really able to figure out what's causing this. It's progressing every day. Any suggestions on what is happening to the leaves and how to get it fixed would be much apreciated. Thank you!

[image]